# Nodejs server on my PC not receiving POST request from AWS instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, post, axios

I have two nodejs files. One sends a post request (using axios) from an AWS EC2 instance and one receives it (using express) on my PC. For some reason, my PC nodejs server isn't receiving the post requests.

I have this code for my receiver:

```js
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.end("Request received!")
}
```

And nothing is logged.

The code is probably not the issue: in all the other cases the receiver logs the request body and the sender logs the response, and the receiving server handles it correctly (putting it in a mongodb).

The cases when it works are:

- Sending from my PC, Receiving in my PC
- Sending from AWS, Receiving in AWS (different instances)
- Sending from my PC, Receiving in AWS

I thought it might be blocked by one of the two ends, so I used security groups and opened all the ports (incoming and outcoming) on the AWS instances, and I went on the firewall on my computer and made rules that opened the needed ports, and it still doesn't work.

I also added these headers to the axios request:

```js
const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With",
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
}
axios.post('http://(myip):3001', {arr:inf}, {headers:header}).then((res)=>{...
```

but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

EDIT: 20 or so seconds after I send the request, the node server that sends it times out, returning `ETIMEDOUT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned below three cases :
Sending from my PC, Receiving in my PC - fine
Sending from AWS, Receiving in AWS (different instances) - fine
Sending from my PC, Receiving in AWS - Fine, as you must be using Public IP of the EC2 instance to connection from your PC

But sending from EC2 to your PC wont work until and unless your PC has a public IP. How will request from EC2 intance reach your PC ?

Comment: doesn't my pc have a public ip by default? the IP i'm using is the IP returned by ip.address() using the nodejs module IP (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip).  If that isn't a public IP, how do I find out what my public IP is or how do I get a public IP?

Comment: NO. Thats not a public IP. Your PC by default is not reachable from outside world.

Comment: If you are connected to Interenet via a router, which is usually the case, you only have a Private IP. To get a public IP, you need to speak to your ISP and spend some money to buy an IP.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/117371/how-to-find-your-computers-private-public-ip-addresses/

Comment: Okay, I used http://ip4.me/ to get my public IP, and I changed the axios request to direct to there, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Because thats not your public IP. Thats the public IP of your router / internet service provider. Leave axios/nodejs aside. you wont be able to connect to your PC from EC2 instance. You need to use the second machine as well on AWS, or you will have to setup a VPN between your network(ISP) and the AWS VPC, which is not recommended for just one PC.

Comment: I get it now. So are there any other good ways to send data (large amounts) from an EC2 instance to my PC? Should I just have my PC running regular GET requests to the EC2 instances?

Comment: NO, you cannot send (PUSH )data from EC2 instance to your machine. Your machine should establish a connection. you are right just make GET requests from your machine.